# Ambiguous error in Xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling

After updating to Xcode 8 beta 6, I'm getting the following error:

> Value of type 'Any' has no member 'cgRectValue'

on the following block:

```
var tmpContentViewFrameOrigin: CGPoint?
var tmpCircleViewFrameOrigin: CGPoint?
var keyboardHasBeenShown:Bool = false

func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    keyboardHasBeenShown = true
    if let userInfo = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo {
        if let beginKeyBoardFrame = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.cgRectValue.origin.y {
            if let endKeyBoardFrame = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.cgRectValue.origin.y {
                tmpContentViewFrameOrigin = self.contentView.frame.origin
                tmpCircleViewFrameOrigin = self.circleBG.frame.origin
                let newContentViewFrameY = beginKeyBoardFrame - endKeyBoardFrame - self.contentView.frame.origin.y
                let newBallViewFrameY = self.circleBG.frame.origin.y - newContentViewFrameY
                self.contentView.frame.origin.y -= newContentViewFrameY
                self.circleBG.frame.origin.y = newBallViewFrameY
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and these two lines specifically:

```
  if let beginKeyBoardFrame = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.cgRectValue.origin.y {
     if let endKeyBoardFrame = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.cgRectValue.origin.y {
```

I may be missing something ever so simple... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cgRectValue` is a property on the `NSValue` class. What you get out of the `userInfo` dictionary isn't known to be an `NSValue`, so you can't access `NSValue` properties on it.

For the compiler to let you use those properties, you need to let it know that you expect that value to be an `NSValue`:

```
if let beginKeyBoardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.origin.y {
```

(This didn't result in compiler errors before because dictionaries in imported Cocoa APIs bridged with a value type of `AnyObject`. `AnyObject` has some magic like the ObjC `id` type, in that the compiler will let you call any method/property on it—with the result wrapped in an `Optional` because it may not exist. Now that dictionaries have `Any` as their value type, you need to explicitly say what you expect the value type to be.)

Comment: wow, that makes sense. I was looking through the userInfo portion of the new doc's but couldn't sniff out anything that pointed to that. Thanks anyhow!